# Blackberry eclipse jde plugin

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I have installed the eclipse for blackberry development from the blackberry eclipse download site https://developer.blackberry.com/java/download/eclipse successfully. The current version of the blackberry JDE is 7.1.

I tried adding the other versions 5.0 and 6.0 using the Help --> Install Software feature of eclipse by adding the download site from blackberry as https://developer.blackberry.com/java/download/eclipse. But unfortunately after selecting version 5.0 or 6.0 the download fails halfway with time-out.

So I tried downloading the said jar files separately. They are

- net.rim.ejde.componentpack5.0.0_5.0.0.36.jar (250 MB file)
- net.rim.ejde.componentpack6.0.0_6.0.0.43.jar (260 MB file)

Then I tried adding them but don't know the correct way of doing it.

- tried putting it in plugin folder
- tried putting in drop ins folder

I just was unable to figure out how to include this Jar file for compiling the blackberry code for the above versions of 5 and 6 along with the simulators.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try again from eclipse download site but this time use http instead of https in the URLs.

Comment: Infact https was a typo. What I had in the list was only http. It fails even now..

Comment: If I'm not out of date, the eclipse plugin used to request BB developer id and password when installing new OSes. Are you sure your id is up to date and you typed both id and password in lowercase? (BTW, recently RIM guys are migrating accounts to a new BB ID thing. I had to validate my old account today as well).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Update you Eclipse with the following` [URL](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/jar/win/java)

`I have tried with this URL and this works for me, you will get  4.5,
 5.0, 6.0      versions API's and Simulator.`

Checkout the [link](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/16874/index.html?name=Tutorial%20-%20BlackBerry%20Java%20Plug-in%20for%20Eclipse1.1&language=English&userType=21&category=BlackBerry%20Java%20Plug-in%20for%20Eclipse&subCategory=), this will give you demonstration, that how to update Eclips